# Web Service URL Problem

Tags: web-services, url, app-config

H!,
I have a solution in which there is several other sub projects (windows application).
in every project I have some web services added.

Now the problem :

how can i set the URL of each web service individually from the app.Config file??
is there a setting I missed to set ?
can it be automatically done or I have to code for it ?

Thank you friends.

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 app.Config file per executable - although the app.Config file is named `app.Config` in the solution, it is in fact renamed to the same name as the end executable:

So for example if my output executable is called `Test.exe`, the app.Config file will be named `Test.exe.config`.

Only config in that file has an effect - thats the file you need to set your web service URL in.